# Beginner python - how to import simple module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a file called fibo.py and import it into python (See here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) I can't figure out where "my current directory" is in order to save fibo.py so that Python can find it.

Can someone please help me? I'm running Windows 10 and python 3.8

Comment: Are you running your python repl in the directory where ```fibo.py``` is saved?

Comment: How did you install Python?

Comment: Probably not exactly what you're looking for but Python looks into few directories to resolve the `import` path of a module/package. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Answer (score 0):

Run the Print Working Directory program to display your current directory. You can do this by typing "pwd" in your terminal/command prompt, and then pressing enter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I can give you a basic answer. I am on a Mac so I will give a Mac example, Windows will be a little different, but the principles will be similar. Say I am in my `Desktop` folder.

I create my `fibo.py` file in `Desktop` and in it is my nice python code. So `fibo.py`'s location will look like: `Desktop/fibo.py`.

Now to retrieve `fibo.py` in my python repl, I will:

1. Navigate to `Desktop` in my terminal
2. Type `python3` to open the python repl (note: I am in my `Desktop` directory)
3. `>>> import fibo`
4. `>>> fibo.fib(1000)`

Answer (score 0):

create the file in desktop and type the following lines in your cmd:

cd desktop
py

> > > import fibo.py

here is what you should see

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.329]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Mista>cd desktop

C:\Users\Mista\Desktop>py
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:20:19) [MSC v.1925 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import fibo

Answer (score 0):

To get your current directory in python you can do this:

```
import os

print os.getcwd()   #<-- print your current working directory
```

if you are running you script from shell window, just navigate to the directory where you have the module you want to import first.

```
path = 'fibo_folder'    #<-- path of your fibo.py module

os.chdir(path)          #<-- navigate to that path
```

then you can import it:

```
import fibo
```

or you could also append that module to your python path:

```
import sys
path = 'my_module'
sys.path.append(path)
```

Or if you just want to have it ready available for import from any where you can just place your module inside your python installation root directory:

## C:\Python27\

Or inside your python scripts folder:

## C:\Python27\Scripts\ folder

Answer (score 0):

In the page you mentioned, python import fibo from installed package of python.

If you encounter the following error after import:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fibo'
```

You need to install the fibo package using the pip in command prompt:

```
python3 -m pip install fibo
```