# In python interactive mode how can i import a handmade module

Tags: python, terminal, module, path

in what location should I place a handmade module to be able to access it using import statement in python interactive mode in the terminal

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62856737/2305443

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Whatever directory you are entering the interactive mode from.